# How to run a HTML file in python text editor

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, tkinter

I just built a text Editor with python to write HTML and CSS files. I'm trying to see if I can write python code where I can run the HTML file in the text editor so it doesn't open the webpage with a browser.

I tried doing:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('file//' filename.html, new=2)
```

I am not sure if this is the right way because when I tried, it returned permission denied.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi. Are you trying to open an HTML file with your text editor (an EXE)?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by *"run the HTML file in the text editor"*?